# Is $x^4+2$ irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $f(x)=x^4+2$. Using the Eisenstein test to $f(x+2)$, one can show that $f$ is irreducible over ${\Bbb Q}$.

Let $\beta$ be a complex root of $f$. Then the question in the title is equivalent to

> Is $[{\Bbb Q}(\beta,i):{\Bbb{Q}(i)}]=4$?

I tried another somehow "equivalent" problem also:

> Is ${\Bbb Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)={\Bbb Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2},i)$?

But I don't see how to go on.

Comment: $x^4+4a^4=(x^2-2ax+2a^2)(x^2+2ax+2a^2)$.

Comment: @Lucian : I do not see how does that help.. :O

Comment: Let $a=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$ .

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial $x^4+2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$, because it is irreducible in the ring
$\Bbb{Z}_5[x]$. Normally this only implies irreducibility in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, but here special circumstances apply. Namely $2$ and $3$ are both square roots of $-1$ modulo five, and thus we have $\Bbb{Z}_5[i]=\Bbb{Z}_5$.

Another way of saying the same thing is that if $f(x)$ were reducible over $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, then it would be reducible over the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2+i\rangle\cong\Bbb{Z}_5$.

---

Edit: In the comments I show how basic properties of finite fields imply that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_5$. It is very much possible that those properties have not been covered yet in a course, where this exercise came from. Hence I include a direct proof of that key fact. We easily see that $f(x)$ has no zeros in $\Bbb{Z}_5$. Therefore it cannot have any linear factors. The remaining possibility is that 
$$
f(x)=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)
$$
is a product of two irreducible quadratic factors in $\Bbb{Z}_5[x]$. The coefficient
of the cubic term in that product is $a+c$, so we can conclude that $c=-a$. The coefficient
of the linear term is $ad+bc=ad-ba=a(b-d)$. Thus either $a=c=0$ or $b=d$. The former case
is impossible, because
$$
(x^2+b)(x^2+d)=x^4+(b+d)x^2+bd
$$
can be $f(x)$ only when $d=-b$ and thus $2=-b^2$, which is impossible. Therefore we only need to worry about the putative factorization
$$
x^4+2=(x^2-ax+b)(x^2+ax+b)=x^4+(2b-a^2)x^2+b^2.
$$
But this implies $2=b^2$, which is impossible for $b\in\Bbb{Z}_5$.

It may be worth noting that both my proofs of this fact in a way depend on the fact that $\pm2$ are not quadratic residues modulo five.

Comment: How do you know it's irreducible in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$?

Comment: It should be mentioned that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is the field of fractions of the factorial ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Because of that Gauß' lemma is applicable, and it suffices to show irreducibility over the latter ring (where such a reduction method is available).

Comment: For example as follows. If $\alpha$ is a zero of $f(x)$ in some extension field of $\Bbb{Z}_5$, then we have $\alpha^4=-2$, so
$\alpha^8=(-2)^2=4=-1$, and thus $\alpha$ is a root of unity of order sixteen. A field $\Bbb{F}_{5^m}$ contains a sixteenth root of unity, iff $16\mid 5^m-1$. The smallest $m>0$ for which this holds, is $m=4$. Thus $\Bbb{F}_5(\alpha)=\Bbb{F}_{5^4}$. Therefore the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is of degree four, and thus must be $f(x)$. Hence $f(x)$ is irreducible modulo five.

Comment: And @Dune is right. The Gaussian integers form a UFD, so a polynomial (with Gaussian integer coefficients) is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$, iff it is so over $\Bbb{Z}[i]$.